# MVC Items on paged ListView

Tags: asp.net, listview

I'm using MVC and I load data into a ListView. Everything works fine, here's the view:

```
<%  
Dim varDataSource As New iSAM.EntityiSAMRepository  
ListViewDatos.DataSource = varDataSource.ListarCruceCertificadosPrecancelados  
ListViewDatos.DataBind()  
%>  

<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListViewDatos">  
    <LayoutTemplate>  
        <table id="ListViewDatos" class="tablesorter" style="width:100%">  
            <thead>  
                <tr>  
                    <th style="width:2%">  
                    </th>  
                    <th style="width:6%" align="left">  
                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><font color="black">Póliza</font></a>  
                    </th>  
                </tr>  
            </thead>  

            <tbody>  
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />  
            </tbody>  

            <tfoot>  
                <tr id="pager" align="center">  
                    <td colspan="7" style="border-right: solid 3px #7f7f7f;">  
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/first.png" CssClass="first" ToolTip="Inicio" runat="server" />  
                        <asp:Image ID="Image2" ImageUrl="~/Images/prev.png" CssClass="prev" ToolTip="Anterior" runat="server" />  
                        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay" readonly="readonly" style="width:100px; text-align:center" />  
                        <asp:Image ID="Image3" ImageUrl="~/Images/next.png" CssClass="next" ToolTip="Siguiente" runat="server" />  
                        <asp:Image ID="Image4" ImageUrl="~/Images/last.png" CssClass="last" ToolTip="Fin" runat="server" />  
                        <select class="pagesize">  
                            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option>  
                            <option  value="20">20</option>  
                            <option  value="50">50</option>  
                            <option  value="100">100</option>  
                        </select>  
                    </td>  
                </tr>  
            </tfoot>  
        </table>  
    </LayoutTemplate>  

    <ItemTemplate>
        <%
            Static varCount As Long = 0
            Dim varID1 As Long = Model(varCount).ID1
            Dim varID2 As Long = Model(varCount).ID2
            varCount = varCount + 1
        %>

        <tr>
            <td style="border-width:medium">
                <%=Html.CheckBox("chkCancel_" & Val(varID1) & "_" & Val(varID2), False, Nothing)%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("WhatEver")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Cancel" id="cmdCancel" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" />
</p>
```

My problem is on the controller because I need to recover al Checkboxes loaded into ListView but the Request.Form only return the Checkboxes that are shown depending the paging, I mean, if I'm using paging of 10 items then Request.Form gets 10 checkboxes, and as I said I have 60 checkboxes (for example) and I need get the 60 checkboxes using Request.Form or something else (maybe a trick :) ).
Here's the Controller:

```
Function ListMyData(ByVal varErr As String) As ActionResult  
        Dim arrIDs(,) As String = Nothing  
        Dim varcount As Long = 0  

        For Each varItem In Request.Form  
            If InStr(varItem.ToString, "chkCancel") > 0 Then  
                If Request.Form(varItem) = "true,false" Then  
                    ReDim Preserve arrIDs(1, varCount)  
                    Dim varCode As String = Mid(varItem, InStr(varItem, "_") + 1)  
                    arrIDs(0, varCount) = Mid(varCode, 1, InStr(varCode, "_") - 1)  
                    arrIDs(1, varCount) = Mid(varCode, InStr(varCode, "_") + 1)  
                    varCount = varCount + 1  
                End If  
            End If  
        Next  

        Return View()  
End Function
```

Thanks.

Comment: Don't fool yourself into thinking that you are using MVC. What you are using is classic WebForms. Nothing to do with MVC. Once you remove everything containing `runat="server"` from your views you will get closer to MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't suggest mixing asp.net controls with MVC. A lot of them require state which is not maintained in MVC. I've always had issues when I use them.

I suggest you use MVCContrib's grid or jQuery's grid instead. Both are great and easy to use. I tend to use MCVContrib's because I like the way it works and I don't need fancy client side processing.

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/

Comment: mvccontrib's grid is absolutely fantastic but be careful with some of the other code in there - when using it in my project, I had serious performance issues. After doing some analysis, I was wasting 90% of my CPU cycles in some badly written MVCContrib code. The bug in question has been fixed and I haven't had any other issues, but it's made me a little wary. Just make sure you've run it through a performance analyzer before relying on it in a production environment.

Comment: I tried using jqGrid (very interesting) but still having the same. On submit I just can catch the checkboxes from the actual page (results are pagined). As I said I need to catch all the checkboxes marked as true. Thanks

Comment: Sounds like time for some Google research. The issue is pretty generic so you should be able to find something. I need similiar functionality too. :)